# Copy integer value of array length

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two arrays and I want to copy some values from one to the other, spefically those values in indexes greater than the length of the first array.

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];

var arr2=  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

if I do this:

```
var length = arr1.length;

for(var i = length; i < arr2.length; i++){
    arr1.push(arr2[i]);
}
```

I presume that that `i` will be initalized and then that length value will never be revisited so even if the length changes as arr1 changes, that won't matter.

But my question is, to mitigate any potential bugs, I could just copy the value of arr1.length into a new variable.

So I could do this:

```
var length = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1.length));

for(var i = length; i < arr2.length; i++){
    arr1.push(arr2[i]);
}
```

or maybe more simply:

```
var length = Number(arr1.length);

for(var i = length; i < arr2.length; i++){
    arr1.push(arr2[i]);
}
```

my question is ultimately - how can I copy the value from an array's current length and store it in separate variable that won't change?

Comment: Assignment of a primitive value makes a copy of the value, not a reference. So you don't have to do anything.

Comment: your first example itself works fine..

Comment: Why don't you use `concat` and `slice` to achieve your goal? you could replace the loop with `arr1.concat(arr2.slice(arr1.length));`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use [`array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];

var arr2=  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

console.log(arr2.slice(arr1.length)); // [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: *"my question is ultimately - how can I copy the value from an array's current length and store it in separate variable that won't change?"*

Comment: var length = arr1.length won't change even though the length of arr1 changes post this step and unless 'length' value reassigned.

e.g.
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
var len = arr1.length

console.log(len) // will print 3
arr1.push(4)
console.log(len) // will still print 3

Answer (score -1):

I would make few changes to Simo Endre's ans

```
var l1 = arr1.length, l2 = arr2.length

if (l1 < l2) {
  arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2.slice(l1))
} else {
  arr2 = arr2.concat(arr1.slice(l2))
}
```